# What does "pacing his study" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> It was a map showing every detail of the Hogwarts castle and grounds. But the truly remarkable thing was the tiny ink dots moving around it, each labelled with a name in minuscule writing. Astounded, Harry bent over it. A labelled dot in the top left corner showed that Professor Dumbledore was **pacing his study**; the caretaker's cat, Mrs Norris, was prowling the second floor, and Peeves the poltergeist was currently bouncing around the trophy room.

I don't know what "pacing his study" means here. I looked up the word 'pace', but found none of them seem to fit.

> v.t.
>
> 8. to set or regulate the pace for, as in racing.
> 9. to traverse with slow, regular steps.
> 10. to measure by paces.
> 11. to train to a certain pace: to pace a horse.
> 12. (of a horse) to run (a distance) at a pace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "study" is a room used for writing, reading books, or other academic work. "Pace" here means to walk in a regular and consistent fashion. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pace) defines it as:

> to walk with regular steps in one direction and then back again, usually because you are worried or nervous
>   *He paced the room nervously.*

So basically this sentence tells you that Professor Dumbledore is walking around in the room.

Comment: That is, definition 9. from the list in the question: "to traverse [travel across, move back and forth] with slow, regular steps".

Comment: Oh! So, 'study' is a room then! That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @dan A study is 书房

Comment: @EddieKal oh, yeah! You know Chinese. Cool!